# How do I determine if a JVM is still active from an AIX kornshell script

Tags: java, jvm

I'm working on some system monitoring scripts and one of the requirements is a test which checks if a JVM is still active. It has happened that the process is still there, doesn't report as sleeping but is inactive. Is there a way to determine this from an AIX kornshell scripts? Or do I need to do some java coding with JMX or something like that?

Comment: What does it mean when you say a JVM is "inactive"?

Comment: You would have to define "active" first. It depends on what the application running in the JVM is doing. Is a web server waiting for client connections active or not?

Comment: In this case it is a standalone high volume java process. When active, it is processing around 1500 transactions per second. When it's not active, it's processing 0 transactions per second.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some logic in your app from which external applications (for example a shell script) can tell that your application is running correctly.

If you know that you have had input you could for example examine log files to see if there are log statements for corresponding output.

You could make your app update some kind of heartbeat. JMX would work but so would simpler methods too. Maybe write a date and time to a file and have your script examine that file. But how can you be sure that your app has not crashed and it is only the heartbeat that is still running?

Maybe have a heartbeat service sending dummy test data to your app? Your app would process that dummy data normally but just ignore results. How do you know that your app is running but the heartbeat service has crashed? :)

This is not a trivial task, but you can get good results even if your implementation is not "nuke proof."

Comment: Ah ok, I'll start checking the log files for changes then, since the system has a high load and should have changes to the logs every few seconds. Aside from that, I just discovered the AIX ps command has the ability to display the process status (active, canceled, idle, etc.) Could this also be used to determine if the JVM is actually doing something or if it's crashed?